# count and group the column by sequence

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that has to be grouped by number as follows.

```
ID dept count
1  10    2
2  10    2
3  20    4
4  20    4
5  20    4
6  20    4
7  30    4
8  30    4
9  30    4
10 30    4
```

so for every 3rd row I need a new level the output should be as follows.

```
ID dept count  Level
1  10    2       1
2  10    2       1
3  20    4       1
4  20    4       1
5  20    4       2
6  20    4       2
7  30    4       1
8  30    4       1
9  30    4       2
10 30    4       2
```

I have tried counting the number of rows based on the dept and count.

```
data want; 
set have;
by dept count; 
 if first.count then level=1; 
 else level+1;
run;
```

this generates a count but not what exactly I am looking for

```
ID dept count  Level
1  10    2       1
2  10    2       1
3  20    4       1
4  20    4       1
5  20    4       2
6  20    4       2
7  30    4       1
8  30    4       1
9  30    4       2
10 30    4       2
```

Comment: Could you clarify the logic a bit? "so for every 3rd row I need a new level the output", does not seem to happen when result is 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't quite clear what output you want. I've extended your input data a bit - please 
could you clarify what output you'd expect for this input and what the logic is for generating it?

I've made a best guess at roughly what you might be aiming for - incrementing every 3 rows with the same dept and count - perhaps this will be enough for you to get to the answer you want?

```
data have;
input ID dept count;
cards;
1  10    2
2  10    2
3  20    4
4  20    4
5  20    4
6  20    4
7  30    4
8  30    4
9  30    4
10 30    4
11 30    4
12 30    4
13 30    4
14 30    4
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by dept count;
  if first.count then do;
    level = 0;
    dummy = 0;
  end;
  if mod(dummy,3) = 0 then level + 1;
  dummy + 1;
  drop dummy;
run;
```

Output:

```
 ID    dept    count    level

  1     10       2        1
  2     10       2        1
  3     20       4        1
  4     20       4        1
  5     20       4        1
  6     20       4        2
  7     30       4        1
  8     30       4        1
  9     30       4        1
 10     30       4        2
 11     30       4        2
 12     30       4        2
 13     30       4        3
 14     30       4        3
```

Comment: Ya may be my explanation is not quite clear.. but as you have cleared the air this is what I was trying to solve.. ! In the mean while I made it through the code by the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to nest the SET statement inside a DO loop.  Or in this case two DO loops. One to generate the LEVEL (within DEPT) and the second to count by twos.  Use the LAST.DEPT flag to handle odd number of observations.

So if I modify the input to include odd number of observations in some groups.

```
data have;
  input ID dept count;
cards;
1  10    2
2  10    2
3  20    4
4  20    4
5  20    4
6  20    4
7  20    4
8  30    4
9  30    4
10 30    4
;
```

Then can use this step to assign the LEVEL variable.

```
data want ;
  do level=1 by 1 until(last.dept);
    do sublevel=1 to 2 until(last.dept);
       set have;
       by dept;
       output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    level    sublevel    ID    dept    count

  1      1          1        1     10       2
  2      1          2        2     10       2
  3      1          1        3     20       4
  4      1          2        4     20       4
  5      2          1        5     20       4
  6      2          2        6     20       4
  7      3          1        7     20       4
  8      1          1        8     30       4
  9      1          2        9     30       4
 10      2          1       10     30       4
```